# Error in Push notifications After renewing my developer account

Tags: ios, push-notification

We have uploaded our app before almost 2 years, but from last 2 months the push notification stopped working.We have renewed our developer account before 2-3 months only. But I am not sure this problem is because of that or not.I also can't see my Distribution certificate in my account.Can anyone please help? I am getting following error on server side. It's a big issue and client is after me from last 15 days.

[image]

Message: Notification:

```
Channel Exception: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
  at PushSharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSettings settings, CancellationToken cancelToken)
  at PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__1(Object state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the APNS certificate may have expired, you can easily create a new one in your developer console and upload it to your backend. This should remove the error and your notifications will be working again.

Comment: I have generated the APNS certificate for the distribution profile but I am not able to see the Dist certi so It shows the profile is expired. Because there is not certificate attached with that profile.

Comment: I have uploaded the pic also. Check.